# BootsFaces selectMultiMenu does not render correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, bootsfaces

I'm on Mojarra 2.2.7, PrimeFaces 5.2, BootsFaces 0.7.0.

I'm creating my first BootsFaces page. I've got it configured, resources are loaded and I was able to create a container with a panel with a `b:inputText` and a `b:selectOneMenu`. Now I would like to add a [`b:selectMultiMenu`](http://www.bootsfaces.net/forms/selectMultiMenu.jsf):

```
<b:selectMultiMenu nonSelectedText="Please select">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3"/>
</b:selectMultiMenu>
```

It's rendered incorrectly (options are always visible, on top of the button), but the options are selectable; also the caret is missing:

[image: selectMultiMenu render fail]

Is this a common pitfall?

I have checked my browsers debugging tools (Chromium) and no errors are visible in the network pane; for example `/javax.faces.resource/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css?ln=bsf`, `/javax.faces.resource/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js?ln=bsf` and other resources are loaded. Also no errors in the Javascript console. So I can't find any obvious errors.

Comment: I think BootFaces and PrimeFaces css might collide here. Check your browser developer tool what is all applied...

Comment: No PrimeFaces rule is applied to `multiselect-container dropdown-menu`. BootFaces should ["play nicely with PrimeFaces"](http://www.bootsfaces.net/integration/PrimeFaces.jsf)

Comment: Should != 100% sure will ;-)

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem. It's got nothing to do with PrimeFaces. BTW, our marketing statement means that BootsFaces is designed to work with PrimeFaces. It goes without saying that every once we might miss or introduce an imcompatibility, but we're going to fix any incompatibility as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug. I've opened a [ticket on our Bugtracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/130). Until the new version of BootsFaces is published, you have three choices:

- Add an `<b:dropMenu />` somewhere on your page (for example, to the navbar).
- Add the missing dependencies by hand:
  `xml
  <h:head>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="bsf" name="css/dropdowns.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
  <h:outputScript library="bsf" name="js/dropdown.js" target="body"></h:outputScript>
  </h:head>`
- If you're the adventurous one, build and use the developer version of BootsFaces (BootsFaces 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT). It's a Maven project host at https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP.

I've also uploaded a [demo project](https://github.com/stephanrauh/BootsFaces-Examples/tree/master/SelectMultiMenu) showing the first two workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was browsing your site and GitHub to find roadmap information on BootsFaces, but could not find any. Can you tell us when we can expect 0.8.0 or 0.7.1?

Comment: Difficult to say. On the one hand, I want to publish 0.8.0 soon. We've been very busy during the last couple of weeks, and we've finished quite a few interesting features. On the other hand, the list of open bugs is growing by the day. The vast majority of the tickets are feature requests, but still, I don't feel comfortable to release a new version with 30+ open tickets. My guess is we're going to publish a new version in late August or early September - but that's just a guess, not an official statement. In the mean time I'm going to publish developer snapshots on Maven Central.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I've just uploaded a snapshot version of BootsFaces 0.8.0. You find the download coordinates at https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/151. Of course, this is a developer snapshot which may or may not work. The primary purpose is to allow you to test new features and bug fixes early.

Comment: Great! I'll give it a go. If I run into something I'll create an issue in GitHub. Cheers!