# How to add a carousel to a BootsFaces page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, bootsfaces

I'm on BootsFaces 0.7.0 and trying to add a [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) to a page. Based on the answer on my question "[BootsFaces selectMultiMenu does not render correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320352/bootsfaces-selectmultimenu-does-not-render-correctly)", I guessed I could just add the resources by hand:

```
<h:outputScript library="bsf" name="js/carousel.js" target="body">
```

After doing so it seems that the carousel library is not bundled with BootsFaces (resource was not found). So I tried adding the [carousel Javascript](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js) to my project. This caused the script to be run, but the CSS seems to be missing. Any ideas on how to isolate carousel specific CSS from Bootstrap and load it in a BootsFaces page? Or how to replace the BootsFaces CSS (if that is going to help)?

If there is no better way I think I'll be writing a resource handler to replace the contents of `/javax.faces.resource/css/core.css?ln=bsf`.

Comment: Let's make the carousel an official BootsFaces component!

Comment: I suppose your original approach should work. You can get the LESS source files of the CSS file at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/carousel.less. Probably the simplest way to add the JS and CSS source code is to add the carousel to the BootsFaces Gradle build file. If you need more help, just tell me.

Comment: Just saw there's an old version of the CSS available at http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=971. You shouldn't use it in production because it's at least 16 months old (maybe it's not even compatible to Bootstrap 3.3.5), but maybe it helps you to get started.

Comment: Yes, I've got it up and running by loading the official Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to include all the Javascripts so you can just load them or even have a context parameter telling which scripts to additionally load.

Comment: Good idea. I'm told you can't simply replace the CSS files because we've modified some CSS files for BootsFaces. I think I'll have to investigate that further. Ideally, we would do just the same thing we already do for jQuery and jQueryUI: if you bring your own version of jQuery, we recognize this and don't our own version, too. This solution doesn't even need a context parameter.

Comment: I took the liberty to create issues at GitHub https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/176 and https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started to implement a `<b:carousel>` component in BootsFaces 0.8.0. At the time of writing (Sept 15, 2015), you can already test it if you build BootsFaces from source.

In the meantime - or if you need more flexibility than my component offers - you can download the CSS and JS files from the BootsFaces repo (carousel.css, carousel.js)
and build your own carousel like so:

```
    <!-- If you're using BootsFaces 0.7.0 or below, you need to download the CSS and JS files
        from
        https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/blob/master/mavenResources/META-INF/resources/bsf/css/carousel.css
        and 
        https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/blob/master/mavenResources/META-INF/resources/bsf/js/carousel.js
        and correct the next two lines! -->
    <h:outputStylesheet library="bsf" name="css/carousel.css" />
    <h:outputScript library="bsf" name="js/carousel.js" />
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:800px">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
        <img src="Valladolid1.png" alt="Valladolid" style="width:800px;height:600px"/>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
        <img src="Valladolid2.png" alt="Valladolid" style="width:800px;height:600px"/>
        </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
```